# How to write Postgres Dynamic SQL statement to evaluate expressions stored in rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql

I am using PostgreSQL, and I need to write SQL statement to solve the following problem with these 2 tables:

```
                                  Table "Transaction"
    Column      |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |      Default
----------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------
 id             | text                           |           | not null |
 amount         | integer                        |           | not null |
 merchant_name  | text                           |           | not null |

                                 Table "Rule"
     Column     |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |      Default
----------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------
 id             | text                           |           | not null |
 key            | text                           |           | not null |
 sql_expression | text                           |           | not null |
```

For example, there are 2 Rule rows:

```
  id  |       key       |       sql_expression
------+-----------------+-----------------------
   1  | amount          | > 100
   2  | merchant_name   | ~* '.*amazon.*'
```

Given a Transaction id (let's call the matched Transaction row `"this_transaction"`), I want to find all Rule rows where the condition constructed from "this_transaction" with each Rule row's key and sql_expression values evaluates to true.  In this example, I want Rule 1 if `"this_transaction".amount > 100`, and Rule 2 if `"this_transaction".merchant_name ~* '.*amazon.*'`

I don't know how to write this WHERE expression.  A non-working SQL pseudocode is provided below.

```
SELECT "Rule".* FROM "Rule",
  (
    SELECT "Transaction".*
    FROM "Transaction"
    WHERE "Transaction".id = $1
  ) AS "this_transaction"
WHERE "this_transaction".("Rule".key) "Rule".sql_expression;

$1 = 'some_transaction_id'
```

If anyone has any suggestion on how to write the WHERE expression or solve the problem in another way, please let me know.  Thank you for your time and consideration.

P.S. In our situation, we will have many Rule rows that are constantly created, updated, and deleted by many users.  Please suggest a solution that would support this flexible system.  Thank you.

Comment: It's going to be hard to swing this using statements.  More typically, you would just have some fixed number of statements which covers all your intended logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create or replace function eval_bool(data record, key text, expr text)
returns bool stable strict language plpgsql
as $$
declare
    result bool;
begin
    execute 'select $1.' || key || ' ' || expr into result using data;
    return result;
end $$;

-- test:

select relname
from pg_class as t
where eval_bool(t, 'relname', 'like ''%class%''');

┌───────────────────────────────────┐
│              relname              │
├───────────────────────────────────┤
│ pg_class_oid_index                │
│ pg_class_relname_nsp_index        │
│ pg_class_tblspc_relfilenode_index │
│ pg_opclass_am_name_nsp_index      │
│ pg_opclass_oid_index              │
│ pg_class                          │
│ pg_opclass                        │
└───────────────────────────────────┘
```

And for now it should be simple:

```
SELECT "Rule".* FROM "Rule",
  (
    SELECT "Transaction".*
    FROM "Transaction"
    WHERE "Transaction".id = $1
  ) AS "this_transaction"
WHERE eval_bool("this_transaction"::"Transaction", "Rule".key, "Rule".sql_expression);
```

Note that the first value (`data`) should to be the value of a registered type. So wee need to cast the subquery result to the `"Transaction" type`.

Comment: I tried your solution but got `ERROR:  could not identify column "amount" in record data type`, so I changed the data type to `Transaction`, and that worked!  Thank you!

Comment: @AndyShih Yes, I see. It seems that there is the problem with subqueries. However instead of changing the function's parameter type you could to cast the value: `... WHERE eval_bool("this_transaction"::"Transaction", "Rule".key, "Rule".sql_expression);` It keeps the function more general (can be used for any table)

Comment: Yes that's even better! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's tricky terrain.

You could write a set returning function that takes a transaction ID, iterates over the rules and returns the rule if a transaction with the given ID and the rule's expression exists.

```
CREATE FUNCTION transaction_rule
                (_transaction transaction.id%TYPE)
                RETURNS SETOF rule
AS
$$
DECLARE
  _exists boolean;
  _rule rule;
BEGIN
  FOR _rule IN (SELECT *
                       FROM rule) LOOP
    EXECUTE format(concat('SELECT EXISTS (SELECT *',
                          '                      FROM transaction',
                          '                      WHERE id = $1',
                          '                      AND %I %s);'),
                   _rule.key,
                   _rule.sql_expression)
            USING _transaction
            INTO _exists;
    IF _exists THEN
      RETURN NEXT _rule;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;  
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But this will presumably perform horrible. It'll be error prone and everybody who can change the rules could abuse this for SQL injection attacks.

Maybe you could use a view over the transactions and add the rules as columns if you need the rules to be stored in the database rather than in the application. Something along the lines of:

```
CREATE VIEW transaction_rules
AS
SELECT t.*,
       amount > 100 rule_1,
       merchant_name ~* '.*amazon.*' rule_2
       FROM transaction t;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=b7955fe9a554faa42f2beedfca0d1298)

Comment: Thank you for these recommendations.  I would like to use the `CREATE VIEW` approach, but in this example you hardcoded the 2 rules in the CREATE VIEW.  In our situation, we will have many Rule rows that may be constantly created, updated, deleted by different users.  Is there a way to include all Rule rows in the CREATE VIEW?

Comment: @AndyShih: There's probably some limit regarding the columns of a view. But that should be very high. Maybe you should research that and see if you will exceed it.